# Highchart Donut to include gauge spikes

Tags: highcharts, donut-chart

How to convert `donut` chart have the same plot `band(spikes/rims)` like in the below example how I want to convert my chart.

[image]

Comment: Have you already seen the Highcharts demo base? https://www.highcharts.com/demo I think that you should be able to customize one of the gauges series for your needs.

Comment: the demo does not have what am looking for

Comment: Are you sure? Because I think that it could be achieved by using the `solidgauge` series but requires to customize it for your needs. Here is a basic demo on which you can start from https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s2fg6jnd/ In case of any troubles please ask a specific question with a description of what makes you difficulties and a  reproduction of the issue in the online editor which the community will be able to work on.